# LINQ Row Index Retrieval Cast Requirement

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

All, I have rows in a `DataGridView` (DGV). To test whether the item being added to this DGV is already present I have written a method which uses the following LINQ query to return the row indexes of matching rows (instead of a `for/foeach` loop):

```
IEnumerable<int> rowCol = this.dataGridViewAttachList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => row.Cells[(int)DgvColumns.DatabaseName].Value.ToString()
        .Equals(databaseName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(row => row.Index);
```

My question is: **Why do I have to cast using `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`?** I had first tried without it and it took me a while to work this out; but it is not clear to me why it is necessary?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `DataGridViewRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView`.Rows is of type `DataGridViewRowCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable`.  The LINQ extension methods require `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `DataGridViewRowCollection` (the type of Rows property) is nongeneric `IEnumerable`. So to get Generic version `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` that can be used by linq, you should call .`Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`